# Retrieve all records from UniStats API?

Tags: php, api, file-get-contents

At the moment I am able to retrieve **The First 25** Courses from an API and they are ordered by Name. What I'm looking to do is to retrieve all of the Courses from a Given Institution.

To get data from the UniStats site you have to make a call to the API like so:

`http://ACCESS_TOKEN:any_password@data.unistats.ac.uk/api/v2/KIS/Institution/UNIVERSITY_REFERENCE/Courses.JSON`

I've looked at the documentation and can't see anything which would allow me to retrieve more data from the API.

[The University references can be found here](http://www.ukrlp.co.uk/) - Just search 'University' under **Provider Name** and 'Scotland' under **Town/City/Country**.

Here is my code below:

Controller:

```
function view_unistats_data(){

    header('Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTA6');

    $data['unistats'] = file_get_contents("http://ACCESS_TOKEN:any_password@data.unistats.ac.uk/api/v2/KIS/Institution/UNIVERSITY_REFERENCE/Courses.JSON");     

    json_encode($data['unistats']);

    $this->load->view('test',$data);

}
```

View:

```
    <pre>

    <?php

    print_r($unistats);

    ?>

    </pre>
```

What I'm looking to do is get more data based on the above API call? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a late reply but it might be useful.   Good to find someone else using this API.

Just add the following query

```
    ?pageIndex=0&pageSize=xxxx
```

replace xxxx with how ever many result you want to return.

*NB they've changed the version now to V3 so replace v2 with v3 in your url, but be aware that this might break your code.

Comment: Yeah that's actually how I managed to get it working back in April but thanks for giving the time to contribute. There really is not much use of this API so any information is good. I'll accept your answer as that was the solution I came up with.